# Installation of Laravel project on Shared hosting providing by Domain.com

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I  am trying to deploy a Laravel project on shared hosting providing by Domain.com , so after i uploaded my project into hosting, seperated public folder to **public_html** and below this directory uploaded whole project in new folder. 
So here is structure of shared hosting :

> – public_html 
>   – laravel_app 
>   – ...

After that, wrote correct connection in **.env** file, then i tried to link in my website, it shows that error message:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

If i add to my website link **/public_html** it shows another error message: 
**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

I've tried a lot things with **.htaccess**, already set 777 mode to folders, but any of variants didn't help me.
So please , if someone know how to get right permissions to public folder.

P.S sorry if i wrote a incorrect post here. RIP english...

Comment: linking laravel_app/public to public_html is only one correct action here. There is not enough information to solve your problem, check error logs after linking. Probably some php modules are required or you're using php v4 :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload a Laravel Project to a hosting site you need to be able to SSH into the server. If you're able to SSH into the server and get a CLI, I would suggest following this tutorial on installing a Laravel Project to a Hosting Plan.

I personally use Vultr as my hosting and have had no issues with it whatsoever!

Happy coding!

YouTube Series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Y4STYfvpk4&list=PLwAKR305CRO_WMJAJxGz6UCViQyAjdjgo

Text Version: https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/